# Variable used in loop condition not modified in loop body

Tags: c, debugging, for-loop

I'm pretty new to C, but I am just trying to use a for loop to subtract 25 from the value of int change, assuming the value is already greater than 25.
The error message I get is

> "error: variable 'change' used in loop condition not modified in loop body [-Werror,-Wfor-loop-analysis]"

Which confuses me since don't I modify the variable 'change' in loop body by specifying change -25?

```
int main(void)
{
    float n;
    do
    {
        n = get_float("How much change do I owe you?: ");
    }
    while (n < 0);

    for (int change = n * 100; change >= 25; change - 25)
    {
        printf("%i", change);
    }
}
```

Comment: `change -= 25`.

Comment: @UweKeim With a little explanation that is an answer. Would you like to make one?

Comment: Some compilers might print a warning like "expression without any side effect" as the value is only calculated and discarded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*(As [of request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317866/variable-used-in-loop-condition-not-modified-in-loop-body/51317938#comment89611660_51317866), here is [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317866/variable-used-in-loop-condition-not-modified-in-loop-body/51317938#comment89611625_51317866) as an answer)*

Your loop `for (int change = n * 100; change >= 25; change - 25)` never modifies the variable `change`.

You simply subtract 25 from the value of of the variable `change`, returning the result and immediately discarding it again.

So instead of

```
change - 25
```

Use

```
change -= 25
```

Which is short for

```
change = change - 25
```

Please see the [the Wikipedia page about the `for` loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#1972:_C/C++) to learn more about the syntax.

Excerpt from there:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment/decrement)
    statement
```

So the third part in the `for` loop should be the increment/decrement.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to accomplish is to print out the number of coins needed to make n==0, just know you are currently printing out the end product of the loop, which would be the remainder. The only reason I know this is because I made the same mistake while taking the cs50 course