# Assigning values in loop body?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, debugging, cs50

I am trying to build an array for which each element is 2 times the previous element. I tried using below loop but am getting error
`variables 'x' and 'length' used in loop condition not modified in loop body`

I looked at this error on this post and made the recommended changes: [Variable used in loop condition not modified in loop body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317866/variable-used-in-loop-condition-not-modified-in-loop-body) but it still does not work.

How come? is it because the for loop elements (x and y) are not saving at all to be used in the body?

```
for (int x = 0; x < length; x+=1)
    {
        for (int y = 1; x < length; y*=2)
        {
            newArray[x] = y;
            printf("%i\n", newArray[x]);
        }
    }
```

To note, `length` is specified by the user, as per below:

```
int length;
    do
    {
        length = get_int("Length: ");
    }
    while (length < 1);
```

Comment: Hint: looking at just the inner loop, when will `x < length` be false?

Comment: Should you be comparing `x` in the loop `for (int y = 1; x < length; y*=2)`?

Answer (score 3):

The inner loop is infinite since you have `x < length` in the condition. I assume you probably wanted to use `y < length` however from your description I don't think the inner loop is correct or needed.

You can just do

```
newArray[0] = 1;
for (int x = 1; x < length; x+=1)
{
    newArray[x] = newArray[x-1]*2;
}
```

Comment: To note, `length` is specified by the user, as per below:
```int length;
    do
    {
        length = get_int("Length: ");
    }
    while (length < 1);```

Comment: @lm.bertrand — that is why we prefer people to provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).